# Lacks permission to complete this action, you need to have 'AddPackage' Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, feed

However, I see my user in the package as Publisher.
But I didn't send the packages. It turned out automatically, I think.

Tried it manually in CMD

```
nuget.exe push -Source "Feed" -ApiKey az <packagePath>
```

And I get

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User 'MyUser' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'. (DevOps Activity ID: #############))
```

I can't understand it. How packages got from me when I didn't send them. And I have no rights to send manually.

--- UPD. The question is not really about access \ rights. It's about how the packets get in on behalf of my user.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

We suggest that you could check if the the Build Service(with project name) has been given the permission as Contributor in the feed's permission settings.

[image]

Comment: Provenance
Publisher
My, User NuGet VS VSIX/6.1.0 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19042.0, Enterprise/17.0)

There are rights to publish packages during the build. I can manually publish by adding a user or his group, as you described. Did I understand you correctly?